# Replicates and the lack of fit test

Tags: regression

I'm wondering what the reason behind requiring replicates is in the lack of fit test. The formulation of the test that I'm working from is the following. The test statistic is
$$ F^* = \frac{MSLF}{MSPE}, $$
where
$$MSLF = \frac{1}{c-2}\sum_{i=1}^c \sum_{j=1}^{n_i} (\overline{y}_i - \hat{y}_{ij})^2 $$
$$MSPE = \frac{1}{n-c} \sum_{i=1}^c \sum_{j=1}^{n_i}(y_{ij} - \overline{y}_i)^2.$$
If there are no replicates, then $y_{ij} = \overline{y}_i$ for each $i,$ implying that $MSPE =0.$ So is it correct to say that as the number of replicates goes to zero, $MSPE \to 0$, and so $F^* \to \infty$? And so does this mean that the lack of fit test will always tell us that there is lack of fit in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't defined the question with enough detail.  What is c? What is n? What is the goal?

My guess is that your goal is to ask whether the fit of a model is "good enough" considering how much the replicates vary from one another. You do this by comparing the average difference among replicates with the average distance of the fit curve from the actual data point. If the distance of the points from the curve is much greater than the deviation of the replicates from each other, then you must not have fit a useful model.

If that is indeed the goal, then of course you need replicates. Otherwise the question makes no sense.